# Projective/Affine variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry

> Given the projective variety $X=\{w_o^2+w_1^2+w_2^2+w_3^2=0\}\subseteq \mathbb{P}^3$, we
>   define $X_1=X-\{(1,i,0,0)\}$. Is $X_1$ projective/affine/neither?

I have tried to prove that is is affine, by constructing a map $f: X \to \{(x-1)(y-i)z\cdot t=1\} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^4$ by $f(w_0,w_1,w_2,w_3)=(w_0,w_1,w_2,\frac{1}{(w_0-1)(w_1-i)w_2})$ (just like in the affine case). Is this legit? I mean, this is not even well defined.

How to solve this question in general?

Comment: If you know that it is «not even well defined» then how can it be «legit»?

Comment: I ask this since I know that there is a method to "affinize" a projective variety.

Comment: I don't know what that means, but surely, as the map $f$ is quite clearly not well defined, it is not legitimate in any possible sense!

Comment: Also, what do you mean by  «how to solve this question in general?»? Do you mean, how to know if a subset of projective space is an affine or projective variety?

Comment: I know how to determine if a subset is affine/projective only in several very special (and trivial) cases. Quesitons like this one I do not know how to solve. Are there some other methods for (sufficiently latge) groups of subspaces? How would you approach such quesitions in general? Just try some methods until something works out?

Comment: Points in $\mathbb P^3$ have four coordinates so that your description of the point deleted from $X$ is incorrect.

Comment: You are right, I'll edit it.

Comment: What you edited changes the question; now actually $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2$. And $X$ is not a surface anymore but a curve and part a) of the answer below wouldn't work anymore, since now the point indeed has codimension 1.

Comment: @karl is right:  please revert to your previous version and just replace your point $(1:i:0)$ by  $(1:i:0:0)$

Answer (score 3):

a) Here is an amazing, too little known general  theorem of the type you request:
If $X$ is a completely arbitrary variety and $U\subset  X$ is an affine  open subset, then the codimension of $X\setminus U$ in $X$ is $1$.
This immediately implies that $X_1$ is not affine.

b) On the other hand a subset of a projective variety is projective if and only if it is closed, so that $X_1$ is not projective either.

**Edit**
$\bullet$ The theorem alluded to in a) is due to Goodman and can be found as Proposition 1, page 162 in *Annals of Mathematics, Second Series, Vol. 89, No. 1 (Jan., 1969)*
$\bullet \bullet$  The non-trivial implication of result  b) follows from the fact that a morphism from a projective variety to an arbitrary variety (here the open immersion inclusion $X_1\hookrightarrow X$) has closed image.
A proof can be found in [this handout by Patrick Morandi](http://sierra.nmsu.edu/morandi/oldwebpages/Math683Fall2013/Complete.pdf)

Comment: Why sets of codimension one can not be affine? Also, I think that  the set may not be closed in X but still be a projective variety (i.e. there still may exists an isomorposhm from X to a some other projective set).

Comment: Dear Mike, you write " I think that the set may not be closed in X but still be a projective variety ". Well, you should change your thoughts :-) (see my Edit).

Comment: My post answers the intended question in an older version of the question, not the present one. Neither version makes sense as written because points in $\mathbb P^3$ have four coordinates and so $(1:i:0)$ is not a point in $\mathbb P^3$.